# How can I use a view from a framework in an application? (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have created a `BaseWindowView` and a `BaseViewModel` in a self-defined framework which I'd like to use as a basis in all of my applications.

In the `BaseViewModel` I have, for example, a method which allows me to add buttons. I can define a `Command`, a `ButtonImage` and a `LabelString`. Here is the sample code for the call of this method:

```
AddButton(OpenAnyTabCommand, "../Images/image.png", "LabelString");
```

In my `BaseWindowView` I have a `RibbonMenue` where all of the `RibbonButtons` that I have defined in the `BaseViewModel` are shown:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CButtons" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ribbon:RibbonButton
                x:Uid="Button"
                LargeImageSource="{Binding Path=ImageString}"
                Label="{Binding Path=LabelString}"
                Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have this in a sample project, and it works fine. Now I want to outsource the `BaseWindowView` and the `BaseViewModel` to a framework and use it from there.

My plan is: In each of my applications, I'd like to set the `BaseWindowView` as the `MainWindow` of my application. In this application itself I just want to have some `UserControls` which should be shown as tabs in my `BaseWindowView`. The buttons I've defined in the `BaseViewModel` should call the defined `Command` which opens a new tab and shows the `ViewModel` behind this `Command`.

So what is the best way to handle my problem? I know that there is no "classic inheritance" in XAML. Can I just do something like define the `StartUpUri` in the `App.xaml` to the framework view or is it "a little bit" trickier?

As an addition: I found that I can define the `DataTemplate` for the `TabItems` (which are `UserControls`) in the `App.xaml` like the following:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AnyViewModel}">
    <view:TabItemAny/>
</DataTemplate>
```

@Sheridan: Here is the question about the `BaseWindowView`.

Comment: The question is not quite clear: what is the problem? And are yo aware that there is no such thing as XAML inheritance?

Comment: Yes, I know that there is no "classic inheritance". My question is how i can do something like an inheritance of the view. I'd like to show my `Framework-View` as the MainWindow in my Applications and just add some UserControls for opening Tabs in this Window.

Comment: @Sheridan, Here is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to start with, let's address using your `BaseWindowView` *as* the `MainWindow`:

First, in the `App.xaml` file, remove the declaration of `Startup` and `StartupUri` properties from the `Application` definition. Then in the `App.xaml.cs` class, add a startup handler:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    BaseWindowView baseWindowView = new BaseWindowView();
    baseWindowView.Show();
}
```

This will open your `Window` instead of the `MainWindow`.

Now onto view inheritance... as you know, there is no such thing in WPF, but there (kind of) is a way around this problem. If, as you say, all of your views are `UserControl` based, then we can use `ContentControl` objects to display them, provided that relevant `DataTemplate` objects exist.

This basically means that if you want to use a particular `Window` as an outer template for your views, then you can if you add a `ContentControl` to display the view. As an example, I have an animated `Window` that appears as a dialogue control with buttons which I bind several different `UserControl`s to, so that they all have the same overall appearance.

In xaml:

```
...
<Border CornerRadius="3.5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBlack}" 
    BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:AnimationWindow}}}" />
</Border>
...
```

And in the `Window` code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("ViewModel", typeof(BaseViewModel), typeof(AnimationWindow));

public BaseViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (BaseViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
}
```

Using this class, I can either bind to this `ViewModel` property in xaml, or set it from a value passed in through a constructor. As all of my view models extend this `BaseViewModel` class, I can set this property to any of them.

UPDATE >>>

The point of using the `ContentControl` and the `DataTemplate`s to connect the views/view models is that we get away from 'hard coding'. I can use this setup in every application and I'm *not* tied to using any particular implementation.

Now if you're saying that you actually want to use the *same* view/view model pairings in all of your different applications, then you should put your `DataTemplate`s to connect the views/view models in a separate `Resources` xaml file. That way, you can merge this file into your `App.xaml` `Resources` section in applications where you need to and not when you don't:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewModelToViewDataTemplates.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary>
          <!-- Add your normal resources here -->
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Adding the Startup-Handler works fine. Do you know if I can add a call-up of a UserControl (it should be a ComboBox) in my `BaseViewWindow` but the UserControl itself is defined in my Application? Also the DataContext of the UserControl should be a `ViewModel` in my Application.

Comment: Hey. What do you mean by 'Do you know if I can add a call-up of a `UserControl` (it should be a `ComboBox`) in my `BaseViewWindow`'?

Comment: I'd like to have something like: `<View:UserControlPerson x:Name="UcPerson" DataContext="{Binding Path=PersonViewModel}"/>` in my `BaseViewWindow`. But the UserControl itself and the PersonViewModel are in the Application and not in the Framework.